# Ensure that same name files will always match?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two list:
this:

list1

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs1\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs1\\merge\\ASTI\\ASTI.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs1\\merge\\ASTO\\ASTO.shp']
```

and this:

list2

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\AST\\AST.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\ASTI\\ASTI.shp',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\AWE\\AWE.shp',  #THIS IS EXTRA
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\programs\\merge\\ASTO\\ASTO.shp']
```

Then zip:

```
final = [(f,s) for f,s in zip(list1,list2)]
final
```

How to ensure that the pairs will match with the corresponding same name on the other list after the zip?

Maybe we match with their previous folder?
Like:

```
if list1[0].split('\\')[-2] == list2[0].split('\\')[-2]:
      final = [(f,s) for f,s in zip(list1,list2)]
      final
```

Comment: `zip` preserves the ordering. It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: in the second list the third item doesn't exist in the first. it will be paired wrong

Comment: And so will all subsequent items, then?

Comment: Yes, this is why it needs to do some conditions to ensure that it pairs well.

Comment: why not `[x for x in list1 if x in list2]`? What do you need the `zip` for?

Comment: you know they are not entirely identical right? Maybe if you use it by checking the last level of the directory that is the same maybe it would work. Can you modify?

Comment: edited to show that they are not the same paths.

Comment: I have to make pairs that's why I used zip your list comprehension doesn't pair it just find the identical paths

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly that you want to get the pairs which match (for example based on the penultimate folder as in your example - you can customize on the condition you would like). What I would do then would be something like this:

```
dict1 = {path.split('\\')[-2]: path for path in list1}
dict2 = {path.split('\\')[-2]: path for path in list2}
common = set(dict1) & set(dict2)
pairs = [(dict1[element], dict2[element]) for element in common]
```